# Socialengine - Get the user id of the profile which is being viewed

Tags: php, socialengine

I'm trying to create a widget to display stuff about the user who's profile is being viewed. e.g.

Andys profile page (viewed by steven)

Andy has made 10 posts on our forum

So I want Andy's user id rather than the viewer (steven's) id

Hope this is clear :D

Currently i'm using the current url and preg matching the hell out of it to get the users unique username but I was hoping that there might be a more elegant solution

thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following;

```
Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject()
```

This will return a user object of the current user that is being viewed